# Read txt files and display it on the screen

Tags: android, text

I'm building a music app and I want to let my users bind some .txt files to songs, those files contains song's tabs, so it's extremely important to maintain the format inside of the file. 
I want to do something similar to PDF readers, I would use them to open those files for me, but I also want to perform operations while the tabs are open(auto-scroll, play-pause song, etc) 
So, what I'm asking is: How can I make a txt reader that maintains the text format? There is any view or something similar suited for that?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to create a text file  to each song and display it when the song is playing ?

Comment: I want to bind them, whenever the user click the txt icon, it will open a new activity with the tabs

Comment: well sorry can u explain a bit more how you meant by bind them ! you have a songs list displayed in activity and to each song there is a text file bind to them and when you click the text will open new activity with tabs ?

Comment: Exactly! I will have a field for each song with the file path, so each song will have a file

Comment: so the text file is like a discription for the song ! and the user can choose to add or to modify the text ? if that the case  i dont recommend you to use a file for each song !

Comment: He can only add, he can't modify directly.

Comment: Its like a description, but it has to maintain the original formatting

Comment: i don't recommend you use a text file for each song , beacause u will have a huge amount of text files and that can cause some problems ! i recommend you to use a data base that contains the discription of the songs, you can set up the format of the displayed text in the ui design.